# Использования стандартных CSS переменных в media queries

Tags: css, css3, reactjs, create-react-app

Всем привет! Возможно ли (и как?) использовать CSS переменные внутри media queries, пример:

```
:root {
  --viewport--small: 358px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: var(--viewport-small)) {
  // something
}
```

**P.S. в сборке create-react-app 2020**

Находил [такую](https://github.com/csstools/react-app-rewire-postcss/tree/master/test-cra1) и [такую](https://dev.to/puritanic/add-postcss-to-create-react-app--5hj8) статьи, но так ничего и не вышло, самое интересное это то, чтобы добавить данную настройку (переменные CSS в media queries) без использования `npm eject` для react приложения, вопрос с SASS/SCSS отпадает, так как использую CSS Modules для описания стилей и вечно импортить в каждый *.scss(sass) файл с переменными или чем-либо ещё - не особо хочется, поэтому пришёл к выводу, что CSS переменные будет лучше использовать, может у кого-нибудь уже есть готовая сборка или кто-либо готов подсказать?

P.S.S. "А почему бы не писать это всё руками?" - Логично, но нет, если дизайнер захочет изменить viewport ноутбука с 1366 до 1440, то будет довольно запарно это всё исправлять, нежели, чем просто поправить 1 переменную в 1 файле за 1сек. Вариант с массовым поиском и заменой всех совпадений `1366px` тоже отпадает, т.к. из-за этого может что-нибудь "затронуться", что не нужно было трогать

Comment: первый раз слышу про переменный в чистом css

Comment: @Данил [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722882/css-native-variables-not-working-in-media-queries

Comment: @MoloF, внимательно прочитайте

Comment: Прочитал, вдумался, понял что все ответы на ваши вопросы находятся по ссылке выше, и о том можно ли это делать на нативном css (нет), и о том как это сделать с использованием препроцессора.

Comment: @MoloF, прочитайте ещё раз